# Using property name in typescript declaration

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there a way to get/use the actual property name in an Typescript type definition.

```
type Mapped = {
  [P:string]: P;
}
```

Where `Mapped["foo"]` is of type `"foo"` and `Mapped["bar"]` is of type `"bar"`, not `string`.

I tried different variations on `[P:string]`, `[P in keyof any]`, `typeof P`, `readonly` and `as const` or `type Mapped<Props extends keyof any> = { [P in Props]: P }` and everything I came up with along these lines, but `P` is at best typed as `string`, never as the actual property name.

**What do I need this for?**

To build upon. Typing Proxies that dynamically generate utility functions using the accessed property name.

**Something like**

```
type GetProperty = {
  [P in (keyof any)]: <T>(obj:T) => P extends keyof T ? T[P] : void;
}
```

My issue is, that since the generated/returned values are dynamic, I don't have a type `T` to `keyof T` the names from.

> Could you please provide an example of expected bahaviour?

```
var obj:Mapped = new Proxy(...);
// where the properties of `obj` should be typed as
var foo:"foo" = obj.foo;
var bar:"bar" = obj.bar;
```

And `obj.asdf1234` should be of type `"asdf1234"`

Comment: Could you please provide an example of expected bahaviour?

Comment: @captain-yossarian does this explain what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done in TypeScript.  There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#22509](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22509) which asks for this functionality, and while you should feel free to go there and give it a  or describe your use case if you think it's particularly compelling, I'd say that there's a low chance it'll happen.  From [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22509#issuecomment-372861132):

> It is simply not possible to model that with our current type system features (because nothing allows you to capture the literal type corresponding to the property name in a property access).

So I wouldn't hold my breath if I were you.

---

My suggestion is to give up on dynamic property keys and instead try a single method  takes the desired key as an argument:

```
const obj = {
  get<P extends PropertyKey>(p: P) {
    return <T,>(t: T): P extends keyof T ? T[P] : void =>
      (t as any)[p]

  }
}
  
const foo = {
  a: 1,
  b: "two",
  c: true
}

console.log(obj.get("a")(foo).toFixed(2)); // 1.00
console.log(obj.get("b")(foo).toUpperCase()); // TWO
obj.get("z")(foo) // void
```

Or, at that point, you might as well just use a function instead of a method:

```
function getter<P extends PropertyKey>(p: P) {
  return <T,>(t: T): P extends keyof T ? T[P] : void =>
    (t as any)[p]

}

console.log(getter("a")(foo).toFixed(2)); // 1.00
console.log(getter("b")(foo).toUpperCase()); // TWO
getter("z")(foo) // void
```

The idea is that instead of `obj.a(foo)` you have either `obj.get("a")(foo)` or just `getter("a")(foo)`.  It has the same functionality but it's packaged a little differently.  It might not be the exact form you want, but at least it has the advantage that TypeScript can represent what it's doing!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeAoGMCGAuGARgBosYAjAgIigHcQrTtgCoAnAVwFMMBfDDAHpBMALZcoACxAATAaEiwQ5AFYp0ZAOYSAPAAUYXAB5QuYGRBh62IAA5c2UAJ4BpLk4B8AClsE9ASg1sbDYJDjYwGB0AFWJvKAJo-z9DEzMLGABrdxA4GGiYAH58gG09AF0YAgA3EABLGRQPMmCYL1gcSxwwJ38S23KBbH5+DAUIEAAbLgA6SZBNL2UVGe0oLyocKn8vBBB-GagQADE6oy4ZLwAmf38AbhhhIhmABhex8AnpuYWl1VWJBtyNtdogDkcAKq2exsADCnS4XluDye0QA6gB5DDLAHrKgALxBe0CT1qDQEQhEcA4YGAUDq4AE1Np9PAMDWpjY+lSpnMlmsdgczjcnh8fkCmBCYQiUVi8USySsPPSlmyTly+SKpQqVRgZMayGarXauC6PT6AwEo3GU1m80WHIcGy2O2JhxOZwu12RjxEhFe7xt33tXkdbCBRLB7qhMPhEERPtRmIwYY2hNdYN9evqciAA)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I am aware that I can use a function for this. I'm currently playing around with Proxies, and whether such constructs would be usable. Something like `array.map(property.name)` feels neat (at first glance) and I want to explore these realms. I hoped that there was a way to properly type constructs like that.